# Flatbuffers schema

Tags: python-3.x, flatbuffers

I am trying to write a flatbuffers schema file or .fbs file in my project.
I have only two parameters to pass.
a string and an array of 100 floating values.

id: string
data: [float:100]

```
namespace FlatbufData;

struct senderSchemaData {    
    dataFloat: [float:100];
}
table startId {
    id:string;
}
root_type FlatData;
```

Can any one help me with writing the correct flatbuffer schema file?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of benefit using the fixed array size feature for an array this big, you're better off with simply `table MyRoot { floats:[float]; id:string; }`